# Change vim's working directory with DIRSTACK

Tags: bash, vim

I make heavy use of the DIRSTACK environment array in bash and often change directories with builtins like `cd ~2` or `cd ~4`

How can I configure vim to utilize this functionality? I'd like to be able to change vim's working directory like I do in bash. I see that commands are ran in a subshell so just using `!cd` doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, `vim` doesn't provide any notion of a directory stack. You would have to write your own implementation in VimScript, or find a plugin that already does. (I'm not aware of any such plugin, and asking for one is off-topic.)

Comment: I don't want to manipulate DIRSTACK in vim, I want to load DIRSTACK and then write a vim function that changes the working directory based on DIRSTACK.

Comment: `DIRSTACK` is not an environment variable; it's *just* a shell variable, not available to a child process (and even if it *were* an environment variable, `vim` would only get a copy as it existed when `vim` started).

Comment: I'm still wondering, have you tried vim's native `cd` command (without the exclamation mark)? If so, why does it not solve your problem? Based on your question and comment, it should do the trick.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but the answer doesn't work for my usage. Vim's cd works by searching for a matching path in the environment variable CDPATH. ~1 ~2 etc are special inputs to bash's cd command that takes the path from DIRSTACK.

Comment: @roro did you ever solve this problem? If so, I'd like to know what worked. Out of curiosity, I've just been doing more research on your question and it's odd how vim can read regular environment variables easily but can't access array environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that bash does not actually export `DIRSTACK`. A second problem is that I cannot find any way to export array shell variables. A third problem is that Vim does not seem to know the array variable syntax.

However, I just found a way to get around all this using a shell alias. This is not an elegant solution, but I tested it and it successfully exposes `DIRSTACK` to the Vim instance called via the alias:

```
alias dirsvim='env D0=${DIRSTACK[0]} D1=${DIRSTACK[1]} D2=${DIRSTACK[2]} D3=${DIRSTACK[3]} vim'
```

You can extend this to the number of directories you want to support from DIRSTACK.

In Vim, you can then do `:cd $D1` to cd to the second directory in `DIRSTACK`.

If `DIRSTACK` has two directories, `$D2` and `$D3` are empty strings. This is not super friendly, because `cd $D3` will give you an error message, but it's not too bad since it just stays in the directory where it was.